# How does VRAM usage change when running prompts async through LLMs?

Tags: large-language-models, gpu

If my LLM uses X GB of VRAM when processing prompts sequentially, does it use 2X GB if I run 2 prompts at once using async support? e.g. using Langchains `await chain.arun()`

If I ask it to run 10 prompts using async, does that require 10x more VRAM?

How does VRAM scale the more prompts I pass at once?